# Trigger SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Hi so I have am writing a statement to create a trigger in Oracle that would append the text to the description of every new game inserted into the database.

I want the format to be like

```
Format: (rating). (Name) is (Genre)
Example: M18. Dragon Ball, Genre is Fighting/Adventure.
```

[image]

[image]

GenreID and subGenre in Game Table is foreign key to Genre Table.

GameID Sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "GAME_ID_SEQ" MINVALUE 100 MAXVALUE 999999999
INCREMENT BY 5 START WITH 100;
```

GameID Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "tr_gameID"
   BEFORE INSERT ON "GAME"
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT "GAME_ID_SEQ".NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.gameID FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

Game Description Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "GAME_DES"
  BEFORE INSERT OF GAME
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
gen VARCHAR2(8);
subGen VARCHAR2(8);
BEGIN
  SELECT name INTO gen FROM GENRE WHERE GenreID = :NEW.GenreID;
  SELECT name INTO subGen FROM GENRE WHERE subGenreID = :NEW.GenreID;
  SELECT CONCAT(rating,".", title ,"Genre is", gen, "/", subGen) INTO :NEW.description FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

I'm not sure where I'm doing wrong. But I keep getting "Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors."

Comment: Why do you need a trigger ? The trigger has no action to perform apart from selections. Go for anonymous block instead. Talking about your code `;` is missing for variable declaration.

Comment: type "show errors" or query `user_errors` to see where the compiler errors.  As mentioned, you're missing semicolons in both your variable declarations.  `concat` also only takes two parameters, you can't use it to concatentate arbitrary numbers of strings.  You could use the string concatenation operator `||` or you could build a nested `concat` statement.  It doesn't make sense to store this description explicitly in the table, that sort of denormalization is generally frowned upon.  It would be better to create a view and/or function that produces the description on demand.

Comment: You should also use anchored declarations for your local variables, i.e. `gen genre.name%type;` so that if someone redefines the length of a column that your code doesn't need to be modified.

Comment: Hi could u give me an example? Because I'm quite new to this and I'm trying to understand how to do trigger operations that is why I've decided to use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you do wrong? Several things.

`TR_GAMEID` is OK (although, could be rewritten as)

```
SQL> create or replace trigger tr_gameid
  2    before insert on game
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.gameid := game_id_seq.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.
```

---

GAME_DES isn't OK, suffers from various errors.

- it isn't `before insert OF` but `ON`
- the 2nd `select` refrences `subgenreid` column from the `genre` table, but - according to what you posted - such a column doesn't exist in the table (but exists in `game`)
- `concat` allows only 2 parameters. You'd rather switch to double pipe `||` concatenation operator.

  - also, you're concatenating some `rating` and `title` *things* which are unknown. What are they?

The following trigger *compiles* but is probably wrong as the 2nd `select` looks suspicious.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger game_Des
  2    before insert on game
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    gen    varchar2(8);
  6    subgen varchar2(8);
  7  begin
  8    select name into gen    from genre where genreid = :new.genreid;
  9    select name into subgen from genre where genreid = :new.genreid;
 10    :new.description := 'Genre is ' || gen ||'/'|| subgen;
 11  end;
 12  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

---

Also, a piece of advice: when Oracle says you got errors, ask it which ones they were. How? Like this (in SQL*Plus) (this is your code):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "GAME_DES"
  2    BEFORE INSERT ON GAME                   --> I fixed this
  3    FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5  gen VARCHAR2(8);
  6  subGen VARCHAR2(8);
  7  BEGIN
  8    SELECT name INTO gen FROM GENRE WHERE GenreID = :NEW.GenreID;
  9    SELECT name INTO subGen FROM GENRE WHERE subGenreID = :NEW.GenreID;
 10    SELECT CONCAT(rating,".", title ,"Genre is", gen, "/", subGen) INTO :NEW.description FROM DUAL;
 11  END;
 12  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for TRIGGER "GAME_DES":

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
7/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
7/10     PL/SQL: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
SQL>
```

Alternatively, query `USER_ERRORS`:

```
SQL> select text, line, position
  2  from user_errors
  3  where name = 'GAME_DES';

TEXT                                                     LINE   POSITION
-------------------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
PL/SQL: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments              7         10
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored                               7          3

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I really appreciate your explanation now I have a better view of it cheers! :)